# Deciding if this game if fair to a player or not-Probability

Tags: probability

For this question what do they mean by is the game fair to the player? Does this mean that the chance of him winning is 1/2 and so chance of losing is also half?

For this question I did : Let player bet of a number from 1 to 6 and let that number be 2 for example, then probability of him winning is, P(2,2,2) +P(not 2, not 2,2) +P(not 2, 2,not 2)+P(2, not 2,not 2)+P(2, 2,not 2)+P(not 2, 2,2)+P(2, not 2,2)=91/216 which is less than half and so the game is not fair to the player. Is this reasoning right or not?

[image]

Comment: To me, a game is fair if $E[X]=0$. Keep in mind that if the number $2$ appears $3$ times, then he receives $3$ units and that if the number $2$ appears $0$ times, then he receives $-1$ units.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: I wrote the below answer assuming you always pay 1 unit to play. It doesn't seem like that's the intent. I'm keeping my answer as is, considering the logic is the same. Just replace the numbers.** (Thanks Brian Tung)

As the comment above suggested, the expected outcome of the game should be at least $0$ for this game to be fair. Let us take all possible scenarios, where $1$ unit is bet.

What are the chances that none of the dices match the wheel? $\frac 56* \frac 56* \frac56 = \frac {125}{216}$, and the net outcome is $-1$ for this.

All three dice? $\frac16*\frac16*\frac16 = \frac 1{216}$, and the net outcome is $2$.

Two dice? $3*\frac16*\frac16*\frac56=\frac{15}{216}$, and the net outcome is $1$.

One dice? We don't care because the net outcome is $0$.

Let's add up all of our possible outcomes:
$\frac{125}{216}*-1+\frac{15}{216}*1+\frac1{216}*2=-0.5$.

The player is expected to lose half a unit per spin, so it is not fair.

Answer (score 1):

Sidd Singal's answer interprets the game with the player breaking even if the number comes up on exactly one of the dice, winning $1$ if it comes up twice, and $2$ if it comes up three times.  This is a reasonable interpretation, but I read the problem a different way, where the player wins a *net* of $1$ unit if it comes up once (that is, gets back their bet of $1$ unit, and wins another $1$ unit), $2$ if it comes up twice, $3$ if it comes up three times.  I think this second interpretation is slightly better supported by the wording, but it's useful to have both covered.

As it so happens, Martin Gardner also interpreted the game this way in his April 1959 installment of *Mathematical Games*, "James Hugh Riley Shows, Inc."  In this column, Gardner describes the fictitious and mathematically inclined carnival run by his friend and former classmate James Riley, and one of the games is the one just described in the OP.

Gardner explains, in the answer section to this installment, from his collection, *The Second Scientific American Book of Mathematical Puzzles and Diversions*:

> A person playing the carnival dice game can expect to win a trifle more than $92$ cents for every dollar bet.  There are $216$ equally probable ways three dice can fall, of which $91$ are wins for the player.  His chances of winning something on each bet, therefore, are $91/216$.  Assume that he plays the game $216$ times, betting one dollar each time, and that each time the three dice fall a different way.  On $75$ of his wins his number appears only once, so he is paid $\$150$ by the operator.  [$\$75$ of winnings, and $\$75$ of his original bet in those $75$ games. —brian]  On $15$ wins the number shows twice, so he is paid $\$45$.  On one win all three dice will show the number, earning him $\$4$.  The total paid to him is $\$199$.  To win this, he bet $\$216$, consequently he expects in the long run, for every dollar waged, to win $199/216$ dollars, or $\$.9212+$.  This gives a little more than $7.8$ cents to the operator on every dollar bet: a profit of about $7.8$ percent.

So the game is a net expected loss to the player under this interpretation as well.

Comment: Good catch. Rereading the question, I think there isn't much ambiguity and your interpretation is correct.